# Query in Node.js using mysql with several loops

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to make several queries through the for. The  `requestFast (i)` function tries to make as many updates as the list size. When executing it, the error appears  "Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit" but the connection is closed at the end.

```
const database = new Database();

let person = [];

database.query(queryGet)
    .then(rows => {
        for (i in rows) {
            person[i] = new Person(rows[i].name, rows[i].lastName, rows[i].age);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < uuidUploads.length; i++) {
            request(i);
        }
        database.close();
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

request(i) almost certainly returns a promise. What is happening is you are looping over the request(i) but not actually executing the "request" function but instead adding it to the event loop. So what is happening is your current function is completing including the database.close() command then the request(i) function is being called from the event loop.

I would suggest refactoring your code to use the async/await paradigm to make this easier to read and troubleshoot.

```
async function databaseQueryHandler() {
    const database = new Database();

    let person = [];


    let rows = await database.query(queryGet)
    try {
        for (let i in rows) { // make sure to declare your variables or you are going to have a bad time (add let)
            person[i] = new Person(rows[i].name, rows[i].lastName, rows[i].age);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < uuidUploads.length; i++) { // not sure where uuidUploads comes from
            await request(i); // not sure you want to be passing in i here...
        }
        database.close();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```